# Getting a subset of variables in R summary

Tags: r, linear-regression, summary, panel-data, plm

When using the [`summary`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/summary.html) function in R, is there an option I can pass in there to present only a subset of the variables?

In my example, I ran a panel regression with `plm()` (from package `plm`)  I have several explanatory variables, and have many dummy variables whose coefficients I do not want to present. I suppose there is a simple way to do this, but couldn't find it in the function documentation.

Comment: if you only want columns 1, 3 and 5,  use `summary(df[, c(1,3,5)])`

Comment: @G5W I can't get that syntax to work. "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"

Comment: The `summary` object is not a data frame so cannot be subset in that manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is in the documentation, but you have to look for the associacted `print` method for `summary.plm`. The argument is `subset`. Use it as in the following example:

```
library(plm)
data("Grunfeld", package = "plm")
mod <- plm(inv ~ value + capital, data = Grunfeld)
print(summary(mod), subset = c("capital"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the regression you ran behaves similarly as the `summary()` of a basic `lm()` model:

```
# set up data
x <- 1:100 * runif(100, .01, .02)
y <- 1:100 * runif(100, .01, .03)


# run a very basic linear model
mylm <- lm(x ~ y)
summary(mylm)


# we can save summary of our linear model as a variable
mylm_summary <- summary(mylm)

# we can then isolate coefficients from this summary (summary is just a list) 
mylm_summary$coefficients

#output:
Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 0.2007199 0.04352267  4.611846 1.206905e-05
y           0.5715838 0.03742379 15.273273 1.149594e-27


# note that the class of this "coefficients" object is a matrix
class(mylm_summ$coefficients)

# output
[1] "matrix"

# we can convert that matrix into a data frame so it is easier to work with and subset
mylm_df_coefficients <- data.frame(mylm_summary$coefficients)
```